# running java applet in firefox

Tags: firefox, java, firefox-extensions, java-applet

I am trying to get a java applet running on firefox however I can not get firefox to recognize the java plugin.

I have both 64bit versions of Java and firefox however the plugin will still not show up after installing Java.

Is there anyway to manually install the plugin?

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there anyway to manually install the plugin?

No. You need to use 32-bit Firefox and a 32-bit JRE.

Java is not supported in 64-bit Firefox.

> Firefox 64-bit for Windows, by design, has limited support for plugins and users will notice that certain sites requiring plugins that worked in previous 32-bit versions of Firefox might not work in this 64-bit version.
>
> As we’ve shared previously, [Mozilla intends to remove support for most NPAPI plugins in Firefox by the end of 2016](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/).

Source [Firefox 64-bit for Windows Available](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/12/15/firefox-64-bit-for-windows-available/)

> You have the 64-bit version of Firefox, where only Silverlight and Flash Plugins are 'whitelisted'. If you need Java you need to install the 32-bit version of Firefox. You can have both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions installed, but you'll need to do a "custom" installation (on the first screen of the installer routine) and select or create a uniquely named folder - like maybe Firefox 32, otherwise the 32-bit installer may overwrite your 64-bit Firefox installation.

Source [No Java plugin](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1105633)